# Select Into From, Create table without identity property

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored procedure like this that executed after insert command for any table

```
Create Procedure [dbo].[HistoryInsert](
@TableName  nVarchar(500),
@RecordId   bigInt
)
As

    declare @Query  nVarChar(max)
    if Not Exists (Select   Top 1 1
                From    Information_schema.tables
                Where   Table_Name  = @TableName + 'History')
        Set @Query  = 'Select  *  Into ' + @TableName + 'History FROM ' + @TableName

    Else
        Set @Query  = 'Insert Into ' + @TableName  + 'History Select *   FROM ' + @TableName
        Exec(@Query)

    Exec(@Query)
```

When this procedure executed for first time , History table created. and when this procedure executed for second time, insertion failed because created table has identity column.how to select into from table for all column without increment identity property for column.

Comment: By using `INSERT INTO tablename (list of columns - without the IDENTITY) SELECT ...`?

Comment: Why do you select and into the same table?

Comment: Use a trigger that inserts into a history table for 'on insert'.

Comment: This procedure is general for all table and I can not use column name.Identity column should be created but without identity property.

Comment: If you use * then the identity property will always be copied. This looks a horrible idea anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks like an attempt to keep a history of data changes.  Consider using [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) instead of rolling your own solution.

One way to allow inserts with the `identity` column specified is [identity_insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON
```

You could turn this on in your second exec.  Since you're copying the entire table, you'd have to clean out the history table before you copy, for example using `truncate`:

```
Set @Query  = 
    'truncate table ' + @TableName  + 'History; ' +
    'set identity_insert ' + @TableName 'History on; ' +
    'Insert Into ' + @TableName  + 'History Select *   FROM ' + @TableName '; ' +
    'set identity_insert ' + @TableName 'History off; '
```

A nicer solution would be to modify the first exec to create a table without an `identity` column.  I have not found a practical way to do that.  SQL Server requires you to drop the column and recreate it, which would make for  very cumbersome dynamic SQL.

Comment: Or maybe [AutoAudit](http://autoaudit.codeplex.com/) if on a version that does not support CDC

Answer (score 14):

There is some lifehack

```
select *
into #tmp_table
from Table

union all

select *
from Table 
where 1<>1
```

Using union all deprecate SQL Endgine to inherit constraints and identity too.

> ```
>       When an existing identity column is selected into a new table, the new column inherits the IDENTITY property, unless one of the following conditions is true:
>             - The SELECT statement contains a join, GROUP BY clause, or aggregate function.
>             - Multiple SELECT statements are joined by using UNION.
>             - The identity column is listed more than one time in the select list.
>             - The identity column is part of an expression.
>             - The identity column is from a remote data source.
> ```

Comment: This is a great hack.

Answer (score 0):

Andomar is right, if you can use [Change Data Capture](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx) you should. If you're stuck on a version that doesn't support it however, you can still work around this problem.

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx)...

> When an existing identity column is selected into a new table, the new
>   column inherits the IDENTITY property, unless one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - The SELECT statement contains a join, GROUP BY clause, or aggregate function.
> - Multiple SELECT statements are joined by using UNION.
> - The identity column is listed more than one time in the select list.
> - The identity column is part of an expression.
> - The identity column is from a remote data source.

So, for example, if you knew the name of the identity column, you could do something like this without needing to know any of the other columns:

```
Exec('select ' + @identityColName + ' as id_temp123, * into ' + @TableName  + 'History from ' + @TableName)
Exec('alter table ' + @TableName  + ' drop column id_temp123')
```

This also preserves the column order.

You can programmatically find the identity column (if there is one) by looking in the information schema. Eg:

```
select TABLE_NAME + '.' + COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
where 
    TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' and 
    TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable' and 
    columnProperty(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query: I found this one working properly. This will select data in columns without identity = 1

```
DECLARE @Temp NVARCHAR(MAX); 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Temp = '';
SELECT @Temp = @Temp + COLUMN_NAME + ', ' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Person' AND  columnProperty(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') != 1 

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ' + SUBSTRING(@Temp, 0, LEN(@Temp)) +' FROM [Person]';
EXECUTE SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL;
```

You can get the column name details from sys.columns table

Try the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') 
AND [Name] <> 'ColumnName'

DECLARE @sql as VARCHAR(8000)
SET @sql = 'SELECT '

SELECT @sql += [Name] + ', ' FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName') 
AND [Name] <> 'ColumnName'

SELECT @sql += ' FROM Dbo.TableName'

EXEC(@sql)
```